# How to use @PathVariable to Pojo?

Tags: java, spring, web

I've created a POJO like this.

```
public class Param（）{
    @NotNull
    private Sring paraA;
    @NotNull
    private Sring paraB;

    //Setter and getter
}
```

And I want to use `JSR303` to check it.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{paraA}/{paraB}")
@ResponseBody
public BaseJsonRsp test(@PathVariable  @Valid Param param) {
  //doSomething
}
```

But this code it doesn't work and I've got following error

```
HTTP Status 500 - Missing URI template variable 'value' for method parameter of type PatchValue!
```

Why? How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: From your error message I guess you haven't added sufficient code to describe your problem. Please be more specific about your problem to get faster answer.

Comment: Don't know if this will work, but have you tried `@PathVariable String paraA, @PathVariable String paraB, @Valid @Value("${new com.foo.Param(#paraA, #paraB)}") Param param`?

Comment: I just want to set the @PathVariable's value to the pojo ,and i don't know how to do....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Spring Refererence Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates) on `@PathVariable`:

> A @PathVariable argument can be of any simple type such as int, long, Date, etc.

If you want to use your `Param` type as the controller method argument, you won't be able to do so using `@PathVariable`.

Alternatively, you can map your parameters to individual `String` variables (using `@PathVariable`), and then manually construct your `Param` after that. Note that `@PathVariable` assumes that the placeholder in your URL is the same as the variable name by default. If your variable name doesn't match, you'd do something like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{paraA}/{paraB}")
@ResponseBody
public BaseJsonRsp test(@PathVariable("paraA") String myParam, 
                        @PathVariable("paraB") String otherParam) {
    //doSomething
}
```

Comment: Your quotation is moderately misleading in that Spring is capable of using anything that it can run through a `Converter<String,Foo>`, though in the case of an `@PathVariable` it has to be a single parameter.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks for the clarification. I've never done anything more complex than that with PathVariable so I wasn't aware of that option. Like you mention, it still probably wouldn't be the solution here, but I'll play around with a simple example and update here. Interesting that the Spring docs phrase it like this though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicity set the variable values from the URL into the Param object.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{paraA}/{paraB}")
@ResponseBody
public BaseJsonRsp test(@PathVariable("paraA") String paramA, @PathVariable("paraB") String paramB) {
     Param param = new Param(paramA, paramB);
}
```

Comment: I know to set a name , but If i set a name like paraA , how to set the values to my pojo?

Answer (score 0):

@PathVariable assumes that the placeholder in your URL is the same as the variable name by default. You need to do this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{paraA}/{paraB}")
@ResponseBody
public BaseJsonRsp test(@PathVariable("paraA") String paramA,            
                        @PathVariable("paraB") String otherparam) {
   Param param = new Param(paramA, paramB);
 }
```

Comment: thanks you , I already know this way to solve the problem ,but i just want to use the param as the parameters .